# .htaccess redirect help

Tags: .htaccess

I'm a complete newbie to .htaccess.  I've been looking around trying to figure this out.

I'm trying to figure how to do the following:

- 1 web server hosting account
- 2 different website, call them abc.com and def.com
- I want www.abc.com to continue to point to the webroot/Default.aspx.  But I want www.def.com to point to www.abc.com/def/Default.aspx while www.def.com still shows up in the address bar.

The admin guy for the server farm I use stated I need to use an .htaccess file.  I've been googling around trying to figure this out but only examples I find will redirect every website hit to a server to the subdirectory.  I only want www.def.com calls to redirect to the subdirectory.

Comment: The admin guy could set this up cleanly using two `VirtualHost` containers. That would be the usual way. (It is possible using .htaccess but only if `def.com` already points to your server, and the location of `abc.com`)

Comment: def.com and abc.com both point to the same directory on the same server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/def.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?def\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ foldername/$1 [L]
```